# How to get Product name instead of sku in email to admin in authorize.net?

Tags: ubercart, payment-gateways

My client has a drupal site where the admin gets a SKU in the confirmation email. He wants to replace that with product name. How can I do that and where do I have to change it?

I found this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1560000), but I don't see the file in authorize.net module to patch the code.

Can anyone help me out.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to modify **uc-order--admin.tpl.php** under **sites\all\modules\ubercart\uc_order\templates**
look for: `$product->model` (SKU) and comment it out or replace it directly with `$product->title` , modify the template to your liking but always keep a copy of the original template.

Comment: Thanks @quddal . need to change the code in **sites\all\modules\ubercart\payment\uc_authorizenet\uc_authorizenet.module** file.